# Output a number that may be one of three types

Tags: c++, stdout, c++17

I have a variable `x`.

It may either be of type `char`, `uint8_t` or `std::string`.

I wish to output the number (not character), using **the same expression involving `std::cout`**. This is because I use this expression in generated code.

At code-generation-time, I currently don't know if `x` will be `char`, `uint8_t` or `std::string`.

`std::cout << x << std::endl` does not work if `x` is of type `char`, since it will output the character and not the number.

`std::cout << +x << std::endl` does not work if `x` is of type `std::string`.

`std::cout << (typeid(x) == typeid(uint8_t) || typeid(x) == typeid(char) ? +x : x) << std::endl` does not work if `x` is of type `std::string`.

`std::cout << (typeid(x) == typeid(uint8_t) || typeid(x) == typeid(char) ? static_cast<int>(x) : x) << std::endl` does not work if `x` is of type `std::string`.

I am aware that `std::cout` can be configured in various ways by piping `std::hex` or `std::boolalpha`, but I know of no possible way to configure `std::cout` to output a `char` as a number, without casting the `char` first.

Is there a way to use reflection, operator overloading, templates or something else 
so that one can have a single unified statement for outputting `x`, as a number?

For example, if `x` is 65 with type `char`, the desired output is `65`, not `A`.

Comment: If you have a variable, you know its type. How exactly can it be one of three types, rather than one single type it was declared with? I suggest you show a [mcve] to illustrate the issue.

Comment: I know the type at compile-time, but not at code-generation-time.

Comment: Please explain the difference. And show us your code

Comment: Can't the code generation generate an appropriate output statement, since it knows the type? Anyway, you could define a function, say, `printMe`, with overloads for `int` and `string` that simply return the argument. Have the generator emit `cout << printMe(x)`

Comment: I wrote an experimental Go to C++17 transpiler. https://github.com/xyproto/go2cpp/tree/so
When running `go test` in the root directory, this is the error:

`error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand type is ‘std::__cxx11::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’})`.

The transpiler currently does not know the types when generating the `std::cout` statements. In many cases Go and C++17 are similar, but not for this case.

Comment: I like the `printMe` suggestion, but it would require `printMe` to be written for all supported types? (uint8_t, char and std::string was just a limited selection, for the sake of the question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just format a helper and specialize the versions you want to customize appropriately. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct formatter {
    T const& value;
};

template <typename T>
formatter<T> format(T const& value) {
    return formatter<T>{value};
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, formatter<T> const& v) {
    return out << v.value;
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, formatter<char> const& v) {
    return out << int(v.value);
}

template <std::size_t N>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, formatter<char[N]> const& v) {
    return out << '\'' << v.value << '\'';
}


int main() {
    std::cout << "char=" << format('c') << " "
              << "int=" << format(17) << " "
              << "string=" << format("foo") << " "
              << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are working within generic context. So your basic problem is that you need *static dispatch*. The trigraph operator `? :` does not provide this. it is evaluated at run time and will always invoke the same `operator<<`.

So you have two options:

1. **use a helper class** with partial specialization.
2. **use static if**. I.e.:

   ```
   if constexpr (std::is_integral<decltype(x)>::value)
     std::cout << static_cast<int>(x) << std::endl;
   else
     std::cout << x << std::endl;
   ```

The latter requires C++17.

Comment: Thank you! This is a concise and sweet solution.

Comment: If I understand correctly, if there are several variables, say `x`, `y` and `z`, there would most likely also have to be several `if constexpr` expressions, followed by a final `std::endl`?

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me. It outputs the char as a number by using the `output` function together with template specialization and `if constexpr`:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std::string_literals;

template <typename T> void output(std::ostream& out, T x)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_integral<decltype(x)>::value) {
        out << static_cast<int>(x);
    } else {
        out << x;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char x = 65;
    uint8_t y = 66;
    std::string z = "hi"s;

    // output: A
    std::cout << x << std::endl;

    // output: 65
    output(std::cout, x);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // output: B
    std::cout << y << std::endl;

    // output: 66
    output(std::cout, y);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // output: "hi"
    output(std::cout, z);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks to Dietmar Kühl and Marcel for the helpful answers.

Comment: Note that this does not work with `bool` since `is_integral` thinks that `bool` is integral. I wish to output `bool` with the `std:boolalpha` modifier.